# AngularJS + Flask : getting data from Flask Backend to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, flask

I am trying to call an api from AngularJS and render the response on the web browser.

### Server

```
@app.route("/data")
def getDataFromDB():
      cur.execute("select * from employee")
      rows = cur.fetchall()
      columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
      result = []
      for row in rows:
          row = dict(zip(columns, row))
          json_row=json.dumps(row)
          result.append(json_row)
          json_response=json.dumps(result)
     response=Response(json_response,content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
     response.headers.add('content-length',len(json_response))
     response.status_code=200
     return response
```

### Client

#### maincontroller.js

```
  var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.controller("MainController", function($scope,$http){

  var done=function(resp){

  $scope.lists=resp.data;
  };
  var fail=function(err){

  };

 $http.get('http://10.62.XX.XX:8083/data')
 .then(done,fail);
```

});

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Learning AngularJS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"     
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="maincontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div id='content'  ng-controller='MainController'>

 <div>
   {{lists}}
 </div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now, when I access the above code using jsbin.com, I can see my api getting called but nothing is visible on the output screen in jsbin. It is blank.
But when I put the same code in eclipse, I see no api call happening. Do I need to do something more to make angularJS work? Currently, I just open the index.html with web browser and expecting it to hit the api and get the result.

It would be great if someone could provide me a working demo of the api call using my code snippet. I want to know what I am missing out.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792831/angularjs-flask-render-template-with-some-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

You need to return index.html from @app.route("/") when you run your flask server. Update the 
script src to mach your flask config.

**Server**

- It's better to use Flask-SQLAlchemy
- instead of creating response use jsonify

  ```
  from flask import jsonify
  @app.route("/data")
  ....
      return jsonify(result), 200
  ```

**Client**

- Checkout [resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)
- What is  `http://10.62.XX.XX:8083/data`? Use `http://127.0.0.1:5000/data`
- Don't shallow error. Add at least console.log(err) to debug

**Running**

How do you open index.html? As a file? You need an http server will server for html and js from the same domain that you make the get request in `maincontroller.js`. Use Flask for that. Flask assumes certain structure of the project. Here is a seed https://github.com/rxl/angular-flask

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial series that I wrote for using AngularJS and Flask together - http://tutsbucket.com/tutorials/building-a-blog-using-flask-and-angularjs-part-1/

It that tutorial, the Flask application and AngularJS is separated. The tutorial has a lot of demos on how an AngularJS app fetches data in the backend (Flask application).