# AngularJS + Flask : render_template with some data

Tags: angularjs, flask

I am returning a template with some data from Flask server to angularJS.

jsonObject - {"name" : "alan"}

### Server

```
@app.route("/hello")
    return render_template("hello.html", result=jsonObject)
```

### Client

#### maincontroller.js

```
  var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.controller("MainController", function($scope,$http){

  var done=function(resp){
    //how to get the response data from server
    $scope.list=?
  };
  var fail=function(err){

  };

  $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8083/hello')
  .then(done,fail);

});
```

#### hello.html

```
<body>

 Hello {{list.name}}!!

</body>
```

How to get the response object in the controller with render_template in the server?

Answer (score 0):

you could put the json on the page as one solution

```
<script>var jsonObject = {{ jsonObject|tojson|safe }}</script>
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: this will not solve the problem I guess since here the major thing is to populate the $scope.list variable with the jsonObject. Once I have the list variable populated. I can access as {{list.name}}. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you the example solution for your issue.You have to understand and you can solve your problem

#### sample data

```
{'result':["item1","item2","item3"]}
```

#### views.py

```
from flask import jsonify
@app.route('/s/', methods=('GET',))
def search_query():
   """
    View which is called whenever the '/s/' this url is requested
   """
    return jsonify({'result':["item1","item2","item3"]})
```

You have to return as `json` instead of using `render_template`.

#### Angular interaction

```
$http.get("/s/").then(function(r) {
                    $scope.results = r.data.result;
                    alert(r.data.result); //verify your response data
                    });
```

you can do your manipulation from the `results` attribute of angular `scope`.

Comment: thanks for the code snippet but I know how to send the json response. but is there any way to send the response with html. I tried looking into ui-router but that is not working as well.

Comment: if the `html` is static, you have to load it dynamically, you could do by passing value as argument to `angular view`. any way in the webservice you could pass data not render template IMHO.

Comment: so how can I attain the same thing if I pass just the json response. Suppose, I send the json response from the server and in the controller, whenever my html hits that route, my scope will render the variable value into the html. But how should I make my html hit the route? Could you suggest a workaround of attaining what I want to do in the main question?